# Iterate through characters in a string and remove consecutive duplicates

Tags: java, string, algorithm, replace, duplicates

I am trying to iterate through a string and remove consecutive duplicates letter.

```
ABBACBAABCB-->AACBAABCB-->CBAABCB-->CBBCB-->CCB-->B
```

My Idea was to iterate through the string and remove duplicates inside a *do-while* loop.

My code:

```java
class Main {
    public static String list = "ABBACBAABCB";
    public static boolean notvalid = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        do {
            String r = Iterate(list);
            isvalid(r);
            //list = r does not work
        } while (notvalid);

    }

    public static String Iterate(String str) {
        for (int i = 1; i < list.length(); i = i + 1) {
            char Curr = list.charAt(i);
            char Prev = list.charAt(i - 1);
            if (Curr == Prev) {
                String results = str.substring(0, i - 1)
                        + str.substring(i, str.length());
                return results;
            }
        }
        return str;
    }

    public static void isvalid(String str) {
        for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i = i + 1) {
            char curr = str.charAt(i);
            char prev = str.charAt(i - 1);
            if (curr == prev) {
                notvalid = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        notvalid = false;
        return;
    }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, it simply loop forever.

From what I have gathered you can't do `list = results` on java as string are immutable.

How can this be done with Java?

Comment: Since strings are immutable, you'll have to do this by iterating through the string and copying the characters you want to keep into a separate location. How might you do that and skip duplicates?

Comment: Turn the string manualy to an array, and do the same thing with the array ?

Comment: You won't be able to do it in-place, you'll need separate input and output locations. You don't need to use arrays manually.

Comment: I posted the way I solved it. If you have a more elegant solution i'm interested.
Mine feels convoluted, and tbh, I tought Strings were array of char by default.

Comment: What is the expected result for the string `"AAAB"`, should two `A` characters cancel out to make `"AB"`, or all three cancel out to make `"B"`?

Comment: the goal was to remove in pairs. so AAAB --> AB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a stack like this.

```
static String removeConsecutiveDupplicatesLetter(String s) {
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    for (char c : s.toCharArray())
        if (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() == c)
            stack.pop();
        else
            stack.push(c);
    return stack.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

And

```
String s = "ABBACBAABCB";
System.out.println(removeConsecutiveDupplicatesLetter(s));
```

result:

```
B
```

This works like this.

```
stack    c
-------  -
[]       A 
[A]      B
[A B]    B
[A]      A
[]       C
[C]      B
[C B]    A
[C B A]  A
[C B]    B
[C]      C
[]       B
[B]
```

You can also use `char[]` as a stack instead of `Stack`.

```
static String removeConsecutiveDupplicatesLetter(String s) {
    int length = s.length();
    char[] stack = new char[length];
    int index = 0;
    for (char c : s.toCharArray())
        if (index > 0 && stack[index - 1] == c)
            --index;
        else
            stack[index++] = c;
    return new String(stack, 0, index);
}
```

Comment: Interesting, do I need to import a library to create these "stack" ? can I make stacks of any type of variable ? Where can I find doc about their methods ? 
As for the logic of your code, I will be honest, I don't uderstand it. If someone can confirm this works I will mark as answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can implement it only with the standard library. You should import `java.util.Stack`.[Stack (Java SE 15 & JDK 15)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Stack.html)

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation.
I get the logic, i'm still a bit lost for what you return ?
I'm not familiar with streams, maps & collectors. 
Couldnt you just return the stack ?

Comment: @a1a1a1a1a1 OK, I added simpler solution.

Comment: Again thank you, This one I fully understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *regexp* and a single *do-while loop*:

```java
String str = "ABBACBAABCB";

do {
    System.out.println(str);
} while (!str.equals(str = str.replaceFirst("(.)\\1", "")));
```

Output:

```
ABBACBAABCB
AACBAABCB
CBAABCB
CBBCB
CCB
B
```

Explanation:

- *regexp* `(.)\\1` - any character followed by the same character;
- `str = str.replaceFirst(...)` - sequentially removes duplicates *one-by-one* and replaces current string;
- `!str.equals(...)` - checks *inequality* of the current string with itself, but without duplicates.

---

<sup>See also: [Remove a pair of chars in a string next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66943775/15551420)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```java
class Main {
    public static String list = "ABBACBAABCB";
    public static boolean notvalid = true;
    public static char[] oList = list.toCharArray();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        do {
            char[] r = Iterate(oList);
            oList = r;
            isvalid(oList);
        } while (notvalid);

        for (int i = 0; i < oList.length; i = i + 1) {
            System.out.print(oList[i]);
        }
    }

    public static char[] Iterate(char[] str) {
        for (int i = 1; i < str.length; i = i + 1) {
            char Curr = str[i];
            char Prev = str[i - 1];
            if (Curr == Prev) {
                char[] results = removeTheElement(str, i);
                char[] result2 = removeTheElement(results, i - 1);
                return result2;
            }
        }
        return str;
    }

    public static void isvalid(char[] str) {
        for (int i = 1; i < str.length; i = i + 1) {
            char curr = str[i];
            char prev = str[i - 1];
            if (curr == prev) {
                notvalid = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        notvalid = false;
        return;
    }

    public static char[] removeTheElement(char[] arr, int index) {
        if (arr == null || index < 0 || index >= arr.length) {
            return arr;
        }
        char[] anotherArray = new char[arr.length - 1];
        for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (i == index) {
                continue;
            }
            anotherArray[k++] = arr[i];
        }
        return anotherArray;
    }
}
```

This is the code that worked.
Turning the string to a char array and manipulating the char array.